# Use Yesod widgets to build HTML pages

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am working on a static blog generator as a side project, and I'd like to use Yesod's widgets as the templating engine. My question boils down to whether it is possible to do something like this.

```
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.String (renderHtml)
import Yesod

main = putStrLn . renderHtml $ do
    setTitle "Hello World"
    body

body = [whamlet| <span> hello world in body! |]
```

That is, is it possible to display the HTML (print, do IO with the text) of a widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than that, since, for example, how a widget gets displayed will depend on some kind of a layout function (e.g., `defaultLayout`). You can likely make something work with [widgetToPageContent](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/yesod-core/Yesod-Core.html#v:widgetToPageContent) and [runFakeHandler](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/yesod-core/Yesod-Core.html#v:runFakeHandler). However, I'd recommend investigating a different approach: run a full-blown Yesod site locally, and then download the HTML that it generates to a static file.

Comment: I was expecting to hear as much after I looked at the source code for wigdets. Looking at the options, I think the full-blown site method will be the method I go for. Thank you!